# iCloud Drive folders dissappared

Tags: icloud

Normally when I click on my iCloud drive, I see this:

```
iCloud

|--Pages

|--Numbers

|--Keynote
```

However, now, when I click on iCloud drive, I am presented with a new folder called `com~apple~CloudDocs`.

All the Pages, Numbers and Keynotes sub folders have disappeared (and the documents within them).

How can I get my folders (and documents!!!) back?

Comment: Sometimes I have this issue. Try logging out and back in.

Comment: @IronCraftMan Please post as answer, so I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging out and back in seems to fix the issue.